# Изменение атомарного значения из нескольких потоков в Java

Tags: java, многопоточность, атомарность

Здравствуйте.
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться со следующей задачей:

> Воспользуйтесь классом LongAccumulator для вычисления максимального и
>   минимального накапливаемых элементов.

Подразумевается, что должно быть несколько потоков, а вид генерации элементов произвольный.
Вот мой код:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.LongAccumulator;

public class Main {
    public static LongAccumulator maxValue = new LongAccumulator(Math::max, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    public static LongAccumulator minValue = new LongAccumulator(Math::min, Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Random random = new Random();
//        Executor executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
            int taskId = i;
            Runnable task = () -> {
                for (int k = 1; k <= 100_000; k++){
                    int value = random.nextInt(1_000_000);
                    maxValue.accumulate(value);
                    minValue.accumulate(value);
                }
                System.out.println(taskId + ": min " + minValue.get() + ": max " + maxValue.get());
            };
            executor.execute(task);
        }
    }
}
```

Всё работает, но не так, как я ожидал. Если все задачи поместить в один поток (см. строку `Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);`), то всё отрабатывает более-менее быстро.
Если же вместо этой строки подставить `Executor executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();`, или поставить несколько потоков: `Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);`, то код работает в несколько раз дольше.
Собственно, вопрос состоит в том, почему это происходит и как сделать так, чтобы разделение задач на потоки не увеличивало время работы программы, а уменьшало.

UPD.
По совету, приведённому в комментариях, изменил код следующим образом, и программа стала работать быстрей в многопоточном режиме:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.LongAccumulator;

public class Main {
    public static LongAccumulator maxValue = new LongAccumulator(Math::max, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    public static LongAccumulator minValue = new LongAccumulator(Math::min, Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Executor executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        Runnable task; // вынес объявление из цикла ниже
        for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
            Random random = new Random();  // для каждой задачи создаётся свой Random
            int taskId = i;
            task = () -> {
                for (int k = 1; k <= 100_000; k++){
                    int value = random.nextInt(1_000_000);
                    maxValue.accumulate(value);
                    minValue.accumulate(value);
                }
                System.out.println(taskId + ": min " + minValue.get() + ": max " + maxValue.get());
            };
            executor.execute(task);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Вынесите объявление Runnable класса из цикла.
2. 1000 потоков (для cachedPool будет именнно так) не даст эффективности - jvm будет между ними переключаться постоянно, а т.к. тело задачи довольно "быстрое" то и эффекта это особо не даст. Поставьте кол-во потоков равным количеству ядер вашего CPU.
3. Random для каждой задачи используйте свой

Comment: Спасибо. Действительно, "бутылочным горлышком" оказался общий Random. Перенёс по вашему совету внутрь цикла, и тормоза пропали. Вынес также Runnable перед циклом, но ощутимого прироста не получил. показалось, что чуть шустрей заработал, но наверняка утверждать не берусь.

Comment: Вынос Runnable из цикла сэкономит память и нервы Garbage Collector :-)